# My USB 3.0 pendrive is not working on 3.0 port! Any help?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Today I just formatted my Pen drive in FAT format from the disk utility in Uubuntu 20.04. After formatting I have noticed this that my USB drive is not working on USB 3.0 but it's showing on USB 2.0!Even I can use it properly.

Comment: Are you sure that this is connected on a USB 3.0 port?

Comment: Yep, I know because I am using this for such a long time.

Comment: Does anything else work on your USB 3.0 port other than the pendrive?

Comment: To follow up with Terrance's statement: have you *tested* any other USB 3.0 devices on that port and that those devices also show up as USB 3.0

Comment: I just conected my phone through that USB port. Till date I don't own any other USB 3.0 device so whether I connected any other 3.0 devices,it is a no.

Comment: Actually I was trying to create a bootable drive using etcher but somehow after that my I was unable to copy any other to the drive so I formatted it thinking to redo it with other app and when I inserted the usb again in usb 3.0 port it was not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem sorted out itself after a reboot!It seems like it was some kind of glitch that happened after I formatted the USB drive. After rebooting today I found the drive is working fine in the 3.0 port.